# Display none when mouse cursor is outside parent element

Tags: javascript

When the cursor is outside the id #sideNav (mouseout) all the tabs should be turned into default (without affecting the current functions), which means that those elements get display none instead of display block. It should have exact the same working function as a drop down menu of a navbar. Once the cursor entered the #sideNav and hovers the first tab from that point the display of a collapsible tab has the property block even when the user moves their mouse outside the #sideNav element. Requirement: the answer must be written in vanilla JavaScript.

https://codepen.io/chichichi/pen/BmKeZX

```js
(function() {
    "use strict";
    const sideNav = document.getElementById('side-nav');
    const navTab = sideNav.querySelectorAll('.nav-tab');
   

    navTab.forEach(tab => {
        tab.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            const nodes = Array.from(e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.nav-tab-sub-category'));
            nodes.forEach(nodes => nodes.style.display = "none");

            if(e.target && e.target.nextElementSibling) {
                e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";                
            }
        }); 
        
    });   

})();
```

```css
.sidebar-navigation {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.sidebar-navigation .nav-tab {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
.sidebar-navigation .nav-tab-sub-category {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   transform: translateX(220px);
   border: 1px solid black;
   display: none;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   padding: 20px;
   left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="side-nav" class="sidebar-navigation" data-attribute="sidebar">
  <div class="nav-tab" data-attribute="product_a">Women's Clothing</div>
  <div class="nav-tab-sub-category">
   <div>Women's Clothing</div>
   <div>Women's Clothing</div>
   <div>Women's Clothing</div>
   <div>Women's Clothing</div>
   <div>Women's Clothing</div>
   <div>Women's Clothing</div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-tab" data-attribute="product_b">Men's Clothing</div>
  <div class="nav-tab-sub-category">
   <div>Men's Clothing</div>
   <div>Men's Clothing</div>
   <div>Men's Clothing</div>
   <div>Men's Clothing</div>
   <div>Men's Clothing</div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-tab" data-attribute="product_c">Phones and Accessories</div>
  <div class="nav-tab-sub-category">
   <div>Phones and Accessories</div>
   <div>Phones and Accessories</div>
   <div>Phones and Accessories</div>
   <div>Phones and Accessories</div>
   <div>Phones and Accessories</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand what a "folded tab" or a "collapsed" tab are in your question, but can you not simply add this:

```
sideNav.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
    const nodes = Array.from(e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.nav-tab-sub-category'));
    nodes.forEach(nodes => nodes.style.display = "none");
});
```